# Get column from ID in a join with group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:
locations, and users. Users have a location_id set, which is a one to many relation with the locations table.

I am trying to count how many users belong to a location.

So far I have a query:

```
SELECT users.location_id, locations.name FROM users 
LEFT JOIN locations on locations.id = users.location_id
```

But this doesn't return the counts. I tried using Group By, but I am not to familiar with how it works.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: PostgresSQL + SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregate [count()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) function with the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, count(u.id)
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON l.id = u.location_id
GROUP BY l.id, l.name
```

Comment: made a small change, but otherwise its perfect! thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked! I changed the GROUP BY back to the id in case two locations have the same name for whatever reason. If the answer works, please accept!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry got confused accepting edits, added it to GROUP BY too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "count" function.  Without the GROUP BY clause, count returns the number of rows returned by the query. With the GROUP BY clause, count returns the number of rows returned for each group.  The items in the SELECT part of your query can only contain columns that are in the GROUP BY clause and/or aggregate functions (like "count").

```
SELECT count(*), users.location_id, locations.name FROM users 
LEFT JOIN locations on locations.id = users.location_id
GROUP BY users.location_id, locations.name
```

It seems clear that locations.id is a unique key in your situation.  If it were not, you'd get another "group" for each unique combination of locations.id and locations.name, along with a count for that group.

Answer (score 1):

You want all locations, so the query have to be in form: locations LEFT JOIN users.

```
SELECT locations.id, locations.name, count(*) as usersCount
FROM locations  
LEFT JOIN users on locations.id = users.location_id
GROUP BY locations.id, locations.name
```

It is correct, but imagine that Location have ten columns and You want them all. Would You group by ten columns? You would have to, but that is inefficient. You want to group on the lowest level possible

```
SELECT locations.id, locations.name, usersCount
FROM locations  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT users.location_id, count(*) AS usersCount 
          FROM users GROUP BY users.location_id) AS usersTable
ON locations.id = usersTable.location_id
```

or just use correlated subquery (my favourite choice)

```
SELECT locations.id, locations.name, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM users 
    WHERE users.location_id = locations.id) AS usersCount
FROM locations
```

Performace of second and third solution would be the same.